# SpringMVC Custom Form Tags

Tags: spring-mvc, tags, jsp-tags

Is it possible to take the HTML 5  tag and create a spring form tag like 
`<form:canvas path="" id="" title=""/>` just like `<form:input path="" id="" title=""/>`. How can this be achieved, would i be required to add to my copy of the spring-form.tld?

I am confused as to how i can create this can someone explain this. I would like to do this so i can benefit from spring binding to form elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For spring custom tag see 
[Create a custom tag library which extends the Spring tag library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097778/create-custom-tag-library-which-extends-spring-tag-library)
As per yours question  following is the sequence how spring FormTag works

**1**.doStartTag() method of RequestContextAwareTag class is called on first.

**2**.doStartTagInternal()  method of AbstractFormTag class is called on second.

**3**.writeTagContent(TagWriter tagwriter) method of FormTag is called on third.

Now let us follow this sequence of call and extend  FormTag class.
The call sequence will be same  for 1 and 2 .But in 3 when CustomFormTag extends FormTag so this time writeTagContent of CustomFormTag will be called.

So our code will be

```
public class CustomFormTag extends FormTag
{

    public CustomFormTag ()
    {
    }

    protected int writeTagContent(TagWriter tagWriter)
        throws JspException
    {
        int result = super.writeTagContent(tagWriter);  

        writeOptionalAttribute(tagWriter, "testattribute", getTestAttribute());


        return result;
    }
//getter and setter for testattribute.
```

on call to code  super.writeTagContent(tagWriter);
it calls method writeTagContent of FormTag class.

```
protected int writeTagContent(TagWriter tagWriter)
        throws JspException
    {
        this.tagWriter = tagWriter;
        tagWriter.startTag("form");  // form tag is here so we can not change it with canvas
        writeDefaultAttributes(tagWriter);
        tagWriter.writeAttribute("action", resolveAction());
        writeOptionalAttribute(tagWriter, "method", getMethod());
        writeOptionalAttribute(tagWriter, "target", getTarget());
        writeOptionalAttribute(tagWriter, "enctype", getEnctype());
        writeOptionalAttribute(tagWriter, "accept-charset", getAcceptCharset());
        writeOptionalAttribute(tagWriter, "onsubmit", getOnsubmit());
        writeOptionalAttribute(tagWriter, "onreset", getOnreset());
        writeOptionalAttribute(tagWriter, "autocomplete", getAutocomplete());
        tagWriter.forceBlock();
        String modelAttribute = resolveModelAttribute();
        pageContext.setAttribute(MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_VARIABLE_NAME, modelAttribute, 2);
        pageContext.setAttribute(COMMAND_NAME_VARIABLE_NAME, modelAttribute, 2);
        previousNestedPath = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("nestedPath", 2);
        pageContext.setAttribute("nestedPath", modelAttribute + ".", 2);
        return 1;
    }
```

So you cannot change  form  to canvas within spring mvc which extends spring tag library. .You can write custom tag which does not extends spring tag library