# Retrieve the form method from Spring-mvc's RequestDataValueProcessor

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to retrieve the http method of the spring's `<form:form>` tag from inside a `RequestDataValueProcessor` in order to generate different hidden fields depending on it. I have access to the form action, but it seems there is no way to retrieve the http method of the form.

I am using Spring 3.2.

**Edit:** I have added an example.

Imagine the form below being retrieved with GET. What I want is to read the `method` parameter of the `<form:form>` tag in order to add a hidden field depending on the method. Obviously, I can't use `request.getMethod()` because this would return the method of the original request, not the method of the form being processed by `RequestDataValueProcessor`.

```
<form:form action="/foo/bar" method="post" modelAttribute="${modelAttribute}" >
      <form:input path="myField" />
      <input id="proceed" type="submit" value="Save" />           
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a pending issue to allow access to the form method in `RequestDataValueProcessor`.

This is the issue: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10041

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an open issue on Spring, but doesn't look like its going to be addressed soon.

Here is what you can do.. its not straight forward though, so weigh the cost vs benefit before you start :)

1. `RequestDataValueProcessor` will not work for you, you already know that. The way the `FormTag` is programmed, it calls specific methods (hooks) from the value processor at specific times, during the execution of the form tag.
2. You can create your own custom form tag, which will do everything Spring's form tag does, either by composition or inheritence. But in addition, you can call your own Value Processor esque class when the form method is detected by the tag. This class can then decide what additional steps you want to take and you can then use the regular ValueProcessor to add hidden fields as you see fit.

These questions talk about how to extend spring's tags, by creating your own: [SpringMVC Custom Form Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415484/springmvc-custom-form-tags) and [Create a custom tag library which extends the Spring tag library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097778/create-custom-tag-library-which-extends-spring-tag-library).

Also look at the source code of the `FormTag` https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/FormTag.java. See how the protected processAction method calls the value processor hook, you'll have to do something similar, but in the `getMethod` method.

Hope this answer makes sense, let me know if you want me to re-phrase or elaborate any point.
Happy programming!

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't look like a bad idea to extend FormTag until this issue is addressed in Spring. I will wait a bit more before accepting your answer to see if someone comes with another solution.

Comment: I would be quite happy if another solution comes along.. this is an interesting problem :)

Answer (score -1):

A little more information would be helpful such as what version of Spring you are using.

From the Spring 3.2 API Documentation for [RequestDataValueProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestDataValueProcessor.html), I see that there are four (4) methods that you could possibly be working within.  In each of those, you have access to the [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html?is-external=true).

Accordingly, you have access to whatever HTTP Method the inbound request was made with by calling ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29)):

```
request.getMethod()
```

This should give you exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I am using Spring 3.2. Unfortunately this wouldn't work as what I want is the method of the form tag, not the method of the request.

Comment: Since the HTTP Method defined in the form dictates the method on the request, why will that not do exactly what you are wanting?  I would normally just look at your code, but there isn't any provided.  Are you  handling the initial form request and then redirecting before your `RequestDataValueProcessor` intercepts the request?

Comment: `method="post"` should be the same as `request.getmethod()`.  They will both show `POST` unless you are redirecting on the server *after* handling the `POST` itself and before your `RequestDataValueProcessor` intercepts the call.  If you call `request.getMethod()` what do you get?

Comment: Nevermind.  I misread your goal.  You want to intercept the `GET` that gets the form, not the `POST` that handles the form.  I'm not sure if you can do exactly what you are wanting.  I'd say that kind of logic belongs in your service tier, but I don't know your code base or your requirements or why you are trying to do what you are doing.

Comment: The problem is that the `RequestDataValueProcessor` is being executed while generating the form in the context of the GET request, but what I want to know is the http method of the form being generated (POST in the example).

Comment: I'm sorry, Manolo.  I do not know how to get you what you need.  I'll have some free time this afternoon and I will troll around to see if I can't find a solution.  I'll post back here if / when I learn anything.